# C++ Passing `this` into method by reference

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference

I have a class constructor that expects a reference to another class object to be passed in as an argument. I understand that references are preferable to pointers when no pointer arithmetic will be performed or when a null value will not exist.

This is the header declaration of the constructor:

```
class MixerLine {

private:
    MIXERLINE _mixerLine;
    
public:

    MixerLine(const MixerDevice& const parentMixer, DWORD destinationIndex); 

    ~MixerLine();
}
```

This is the code that calls the constructor (MixerDevice.cpp):

```
void MixerDevice::enumerateLines() {
    
    DWORD numLines = getDestinationCount();
    for(DWORD i=0;i<numLines;i++) {
        
        MixerLine mixerLine( this, i );
        // other code here removed
    }
}
```

Compilation of MixerDevice.cpp fails with this error:

> Error 3   error C2664: 'MixerLine::MixerLine(const MixerDevice &,DWORD)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'MixerDevice *const ' to 'const MixerDevice &'

But I thought pointer values could be assigned to references, e.g.

```
Foo* foo = new Foo();
Foo& bar = foo;
```

Comment: `const MixerDevice& const parentMixer` the second `const` is unnecessary since references (unlike pointers) cannot be reseated to reference another object.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`this` is a pointer, to get a reference you have to dereference (`*this`) it:

```
MixerLine mixerLine( *this, i );
```

Answer (score 3):

You should dereference `this`, because `this` is a pointer, not a reference. To correct your code you should write

```
for(DWORD i=0;i<numLines;i++) {

    MixerLine mixerLine( *this, i ); // Ok, this dereferenced
    // other code here removed
}
```

**Note:** the second `const` at the constructor's parameter `const MixerDevice& const parentMixer` is completely useless.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a reference from a pointer you need to *dereference* the pointer, as it has already been mentioned. Additionally (maybe due to copying into the question?) the constructor should not compile:

```
const MixerDevice& const parentMixer
```

That is not a proper type, references cannot be const qualified, only the referred type can be, so the two (exactly equivalent) options are:

```
const MixerDevice& parentMixer
MixerDevice const& parentMixer
```

(Note that the `const` qualifying of `MixerDevice` can be done at either way, and it means exactly the same).

Comment: Yes, I removed the second const modifier and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer values can be assigned to pointers, but not to references!<sup>1</sup>

```
Foo* foo = new Foo();
Foo& bar = *foo;
           ^
           ^
```

---

<sub>1. Well, they can be used to initialise references-to-pointers, but that's not what you have here...</sub>